# Telethon TelegramClient leads to exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: python-3.x, telethon, error-code

Using PyCharm 2023.2.5, Python 3.11.1 and the following code

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events
class telegram_messenger:
    def __init__(self):
        api_id = '123'
        api_hash = 'ABC'
        bot_token = 'ZZZ'
        client = TelegramClient('bot', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token)
```

I am getting the response `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`. If I uncomment the line `client = ...`, the code runs perfectly fine. What's going on here?

Comment: Do you have `cryptg` installed? If you enable `logging.INFO` before importing the client, what does it show?

Comment: No, I don't have cryptg installed - should I? I didn't see it in the Telethon documentation. By "before importing the client", you mean between `bot_token = ...` and `client = ...`? Or do you mean in the `main.py`?

Comment: By "before importing the client" I mean before `from telethon import TelegramClient`. In any case, your Python install might be broken, so you should consider reinstalling both Python and the library.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I tried reinstalling 3.11 but the error keeps on occuring. An upgrade to 3.12 works indeed but leads to other issues in other parts of my code. After a downgrade to 3.10 it seems to work now.